# is it possible to use azure b2c mfa only for certain pages?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we have following use case:
1. User SignUp-In so he can see certain areas of our web page. (NO mfa needed) /*
2. User can change his bank account / cc number. (mfa needed) /bank

Is this possible to develope with azure b2c?

regards
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the application read the `acr` claim of the current id_token. If the `acr` value is not of the policy which is required to access a certain part of the website, then launch a policy which will satisfy the requirement. This is what we call step up.

I have a demo [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/twilio-mfa-psd2).
In this demo the user signs in with normal Sign In/Up policy. When they try to click a button in the app (to send money), they must go via another B2C policy which contains the MFA step.

See [this line](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/twilio-mfa-psd2/source-code/PSD2%20Demo%20App/TaskWebApp/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L45) on how i do the check for acr value.

See [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/twilio-mfa-psd2/source-code/PSD2%20Demo%20App/TaskWebApp/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L80) and [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/twilio-mfa-psd2/source-code/PSD2%20Demo%20App/TaskWebApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L26) on how i force a new auth with a new b2c policy id. (id_token_hint is relevant to that sample and can be ignored in your case).